# Insert values in datatable in many lines

Tags: c#, asp.net

With the code below, I can insert the selected values of the checkboxes into a single line in the database.In the same line, it is added the date, a note, and an Id number from another table (not unique). In my .aspx page there is a simple treenode-checkboxes structure.

Now, I want to insert each selected value from the checkbox in his own line in the database table.

For example: 3 checkboxes are selected: 3 lines with each own value inserted (plus the same date, note, Id for all of them) in the database.
Please any ideas how to do it?

```
 protected void btn_vac_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pa_id"]);

            string vn = string.Empty;
            if (TreeView1.CheckedNodes.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
                {

                    vn += string.Format("{0}", node.Text);
                }

            }

            try
            {

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();


                if (note_vac.Text.Length != 0)
                {
                    string insert_emer = "insert into P_vaccines (V_name,P_Id,Note,Date) values (@vn,@p_id,@note,@Date) ";
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insert_emer, conn);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vn", string.Format("{0}", vn));
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_id", id);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note", note_vac.Text);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                    string insert_emer = "insert into P_vaccines (V_name,P_Id,Date) values (@vn,@p_id,@Date) ";
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insert_emer, conn);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vn", string.Format("{0}", vn));
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_id", id);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }


                Response.Write("<script>alert('Success!')</script>");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error :" + ex.ToString());
            }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try to move the Whole database insert code inside the foreach looping on the checked nodes?

Comment: @Steve Yes, and it shows as many lines as the values selected, but in the lines there are all the values selected and not only each one. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code could be simplified a lot. First, you should prepare the command before entering the foreach loop over the checked indices. This means, creating the connection and the command then inside the loop just update the values of the parameters that need to change. Something like this.

```
protected void btn_vac_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TreeView1.CheckedNodes.Count > 0)
    {
       try
       {
            string insert_text = "insert into P_vaccines (V_name,P_Id,Note,[Date]) values (@vn,@p_id,@note,@Date) ";
            using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insert_text, conn))
            {
                com.Parameters.Add("@vn", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                com.Parameters.Add("@p_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pa_id"]);
                com.Parameters.Add("@note", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                com.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                conn.Open();
                foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
                {
                    com.Parameters["@vn"].Value = node.Text;
                    com.Parameters["@note"].Value = note_vac.Text.Length > 0 ? note_vac.Text : DbNull.Value;
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
           }
           Response.Write("<script>alert('Success!')</script>");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error :" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Your original problem was caused by the `vn +=...` statement that concatenates together all the checked nodes. In this code instead I change that value directly on the Parameter with the value of the current check.

Note also that I have removed the AddWithValue calls that [is known to be pretty a bad practice](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). But this means that you should be precise on the datatype of the values that you pass to your database engine. For example that datetime passed as string is a lot suspicious.

I should also add that having a column named Date is very confusing because there is a DataType with that name and if you want to use that column name it is better to encapsulate it with square brackets to avoid Syntax errors (or rename the column)

Comment: Thanks! but com.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();  Visual studio has underlined the whole line as  an error.

Comment: Ah sorry you just edited that. May i ask you, what is Dbnull.Value? It doesnt recognise that "does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Yes [DbNull.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx) here. Pay attention to case in C#